# "No such file or directory" when comparing numbers in bash

Tags: bash

I'm getting an strange error.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter a number"
read var
declare -i num
num=0
        while ($num<$var)
        do
                echo "$num"
        done
```

./loop: line 5: 6: No such file or directory

What am I mistaking?

Answer (score 16):

`(...)` starts a subshell and runs the specified commands inside it. This is why `($num<$var)` generates that error message; it can't find the file corresponding to `$var` to pass into the command corresponding to `$num`.

You probably wanted something like

```
while (( num < var )); do
  echo "$num"
done
```

`((...))` is an arithmetic expansion. It will compute the value of the expression inside. In this case it will compare the values of the two variables (the `$` in front of them are not needed here).  If the comparison is true, then the while-loop will run one more iteration.

The while-loop is also an endless loop, since you do not increment `num` nor decrement `var`.

In the end, you might want to try

```
for (( num = 0; num < var; ++num )); do
  echo "$num"
done
```

or

```
for (( num = 0; num < var; ++num )); do
  printf '%d\n' "$num"
done
```

If you know C or a language with C-like syntax, then you'll recognize this type of for-loop.